# grails using uuid as id and mapping to to binary column

Tags: mysql, grails, groovy

I want to use a UUID for the id for my domain objects. The idea is that the uuid could be provided by a client and if not a UUID will be generated. I have the definition as like so :  :

```
class Person {
        static mapping = {
        id generator:'assigned' 
        }

        String id

        def getUUID  ={
            return java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        }


          transient beforeInsert = {
            if ( id == null || id.equals(""))
                      id = getUUID();
           }
}
```

Now assuming I strip the dashes out that are included in the java UUID or client provided UUID  I'd like this to be stored in a binary field in my MySQL database. And also on retrieval have the correct format to send back.

How can I accomplish that? Thoughts on a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grails and hibernate usually handle UUIDs in their string form.  Using binary UUIDs is possible with a little more work.  Declare `id` to be of type `UUID` and provide a hibernate user type to serialize it as an array of bytes.  You'll also need to tell grails what SQL type to use for the UUID.  For example:

```
class Person {
    static mapping = {
        id generator:'assigned', type: UUIDUserType, sqlType: 'varbinary(16)'
    }

    UUID id

    def beforeInsert = {
        if (!id) {
            id = UUID.randomUUID()
        }
    }
}
```

The user type for UUID is:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.LongBuffer
import java.sql.ResultSet
import java.sql.PreparedStatement
import java.sql.Types
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType

public class UUIDUserType implements UserType {

    int[] sqlTypes() { [Types.VARBINARY] as int [] }
    Class returnedClass() { UUID }

    Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] names, owner) {
        byte[] value = resultSet.getBytes(names[0])
        return value ? bytesToUuid(value) : null
    }

    void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement statement, value, int index) {
        if (value == null) {
                statement.setNull(index, Types.VARBINARY)
        } else {
                statement.setBytes(index, uuidToBytes(value))
        }
    }

    boolean equals(x, y) { x == y }
    int hashCode(x) { x.hashCode() }
    Object deepCopy(value) { value }
    boolean isMutable() { false }
    Serializable disassemble(value) { value }
    Object assemble(Serializable cached, owner) { cached }
    def replace(original, target, owner) { original }

    static byte[] uuidToBytes(uuid) {
        def bytes = new byte[16];
        ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).asLongBuffer().with {
            put(0, uuid.mostSignificantBits)
            put(1, uuid.leastSignificantBits)
        }
        bytes
    }

    static UUID bytesToUuid(bytes) {
        ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).asLongBuffer().with {
            new UUID(get(0), get(1))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesnt work on MySQL : 2011-02-27 10:18:33,818 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Unsuccessful: create table person (id tinyblob not null, version bigint not null, primary key (id))
2011-02-27 10:18:33,819 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - BLOB/TEXT column 'id' used in key specification without a key length
2011-02-27 10:18:36,702 [main] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Table 'testuuid.person' doesn't exist

Comment: Oops, you're right.  I assumed grails handled non-String UUIDs automatically, but turns out it doesn't.  I've updated the answer with a fix.

Comment: ahh yes a custom usertype. i would have thought grails or hibernate would have taken care of that for us. Overall the solution works..however grails/hibernate is having a problem for the belongsTo relationships when using varbinary(16) as the primary key for entities. The only solution seems to be to create the database scheme manually first.